# Possible to write a loop in Python that stores user input for future manipulation without using append?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I'm a beginner and my textbook just covered *iterations* and *loops* in Python. Lists have only been given cursory coverage at this point.

The exercise I'm struggling with is this:  Write a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters "done". Once "done" is entered print out the total, count and average of all the numbers.  If the user enters anything other than a number, detect their mistake using *try* and *except* and print an error message and skip to the next number.

All of this I can manage, except for how to get the program to store multiple user inputs. No matter what I write I only end manipulating the last number entered. Considering we haven't formally covered lists yet I find it hard to believe I should be using *append*, and therefore must be overthinking this problem to death.

Any and all advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Show your code, and why do you believe you shouldn't you use append? It is the best and most pythonic way to do so.

Comment: Please show your code, so we can help you fix it. You don't need a list here. You just need to store the total and the count. Then compute the average at the end.

Comment: Cleaning up the code now, will post shortly.                                                       I agree that append is the best and most pythonic way to do this. The only reason I feel like I shouldn't be using it is technically I'm not supposed to know how yet. I only know it's an option because I've been researching this exercise for a week now and append seems to be the best and only choice.  I feel like there must be another, if less elegant way, to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: That's an interesting course/textbook as data structures (i.e., tuples, dicts, lists) should precede function and processes like iterations and loops. Loop over what?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to remember the sum and the number of inputs in two variables that are updated when the user writes a number.
When the user enters 'done', compute the mean (sum / number_of_inputs).